# Adding multiple borders to detect nodes on and off screen

Tags: swift, ios8, sprite-kit, collision-detection, skphysicsbody

I am using Sprite Kit to add some circle icons to a scene. I have added some code to create a border around the outside of the scene size this is used to detect contact and remove the node from parent.

```
    // Outside border collision detection
    var largeBorder = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)
    largeBorder.origin.x -= (mainIconRef.size.width + mainIconRef.size.width/3)
    largeBorder.origin.y -= (mainIconRef.size.height + mainIconRef.size.height/3)
    largeBorder.size.width += ((mainIconRef.size.width + mainIconRef.size.width/3) * 2)
    largeBorder.size.height += ((mainIconRef.size.height + mainIconRef.size.height/3) * 2)

    let pathMainView = CGPathCreateWithRect(largeBorder, nil)
    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody (edgeLoopFromPath: pathMainView)
    self.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderCategory.Wall.rawValue
    self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ColliderCategory.Tap1.rawValue | ColliderCategory.Tap2.rawValue | ColliderCategory.Tap3.rawValue | ColliderCategory.TapFire.rawValue
    self.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
```

This is all working as expected. What I would like to do now is add another path/border/box in the middle of the screen and detect when the icons contact this. This is so I can tell they are at least a certain part of the size on the screen/scene itself.

What I am not sure about is that we set the `self.physicsBody` above. I do not want to override to it, I just want to add an additional border which is invisible (not shown) that I can track contact with (not collision). Is this possible without adding as a node?

Comment: I think what you want is to add an (invisible) node with a physics body the shape you want in order to do this.  Put this central physics body in its own category to make it easy to detect.  You must have done something similar with your screen border?

Comment: I think you're right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use an invisible node? Just turn off the physics for the node and pick the right shape for the physicsbody.

Set the right collisionbitmask, categorybitmask, contactbitmask etc and the icons will pass through the node and register "contact".

It'll do all of what you want.
Why don't you want to use a node?